# Bootstrap 3 list item has a stuck background-color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a list item that has a stuck background-color. The list item is "Contact" and the background-color is black. When the page loads, this list item's background-color starts off as black which I don't understand why. I don't want it to start off with any background-color. I noticed the .navbar-inverse class causes this to happen, but then when I take it out, and shorten my browser to the size of a mobile viewport, my icon-bar button which is supposed to collapse/extend the navbar disappears. So it causes that problem when I take out .navbar-inverse. 
Here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/capozzic1/full/JKmZzZ/

Here is the code:

```
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavBar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DreamerCC</a>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavBar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

      <li><a href="#abtsec">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#ptfsec">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#ctcsec">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class that gives it the black background is `.navbar-nav>.active>a`.

Add `background-color: transparent` to that element in your stylesheet.

```
.navbar-nav>.active>a {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom style and set it's background color with !important so that it will override the navbar-inverse default black color.

let me know if you understand that!